# Auto populate Login ID in single line text in SharePoint Survey

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, survey-list

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I have created a survey form which contains User ID related question. I would like to populate current User info in that field.

1. I tried by using [Me] as calculate the value in single line text item. It is working partially as I see some junk characters prefixed with Domain Name/Username. So I am unable to use it.
2. I try to Add Current User Filter and text filter in web parts, but it value displayed in text Filter, I am unable to save it in the survey response.

Kindly suggest how I can populate username in Survey text box?

Appreciate detailed explanation.

Comment: Would you feel comfortable using JavaScript? If it were me, I would use JSLink and the _spPageContextInfo object to populate it. Otherwise, have you tried a person/group field instead of plain text? Why do you need plain text?

Comment: Hi @Sive, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge :) Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 2):

The current user information available on SharePoint page which you can get it from the JavaScript and assign to your textboxes.

I am using jQuery in the following syntax

```
<input type="text" id="txtUserId" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
   var userEmail = _spPageContextInfo.userEmail;
   var userDisplayName = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
   var userLogin = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;

   //If you want to assign user id to textbox
   $("#txtUserId").val(userId);
});
</script>
```